# I am facing issue while reading request body in Azure function node js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

In my azure function post call i am passing body like this

```
{
    "license":{
        "licensepolicy": "NA",
        "metadata":{
            "tenantname":"tenantname",
        },
        "licensetype":"type"
    },
    "customer":{
        "name":"TEst User",
        "emailaddress":"email",
        "company":"test"
    }
}
```

In my code I am accessing this request body like below

```
context.log(req.body.license);
```

Its giving undefined log, I don't know why but its working in normal node js code but in azure function its not working.

Please assist me if I am wrong somewhere

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check your post method whether it contains the **Header** `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

```js
 headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
```

If you are not sending the Json response you have to **convert that into Json object** in your code to retrieve that information.

```js
# convert request into Json object and access those informations.

const parsedData = JSON.parse(req)
context.log(parsedData.body.license);
```

Comment: i am already adding content type json headers

Comment: are you parsing the Json Request/Response?